# Is it possible to scope Jetty 9.4 JNDI Transaction on webapp context level?

Tags: resources, jetty, jndi, jetty-9

JNDI Transactions seemed to be scoped on a webapp context level on Jetty 6, moving to Jetty 9 it seems to be working differently.

Anyone here can explain how does Jetty 9.4 JNDI Transaction works? From what I have read http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/jndi-configuration.html#configuring-xa-transactions, it looks like it is scoped on a server level. Is it still possible to define it on an environment level?